# Mongodb aggregate - Sort then get surrounding documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to write a mongodb aggregate to apply a 2-level sort and then get the 2 documents before and after a particular document in the sorted set. To start, I'm trying to build a query for the "after" document

Documents are inserted out of order:

```
db.test.insertMany([
   { name: 'V', type: 'Trap' }, 
   { name: 'J', type: 'Magic' },
   { name: 'B', type: 'Effect' }
])
```

To sort alphabetically within each `type` I can do:

```
db.test.aggregate([{ "$sort": { type: 1, name: 1 } }])

Result:
{ name: 'B', type: 'Effect' }
{ name: 'J', type: 'Magic' }
{ name: 'V', type: 'Trap' }
```

I'm trying to use the following query (with  replacements) to get the "after" document:

```
[
  { $sort: { type: 1, name: 1 } },
  {
    $match: {
      name: {
        $gt: <name>,
      },
      type: {
        $gte: <type>,
      },
    },
  },
  { $limit: 1 }
]
```

For example:

Document `{ name: 'K', type: 'Trap' }` should go between J & V.

- The above query correctly gives "V".

Document `{ name: 'C', type: 'Effect' }` should go between B & J.

- The above query correctly gives "J".

However, document`{ name: 'K', type: 'Effect' }` also needs to go between  B & J since it should remain in the "Effect" grouping.

- The query incorrectly returns "V" again (should be J).

Removing either of the $match properties gives incorrect results in other cases. Can't seem to use $and/or to get correct results in all cases either

For the reverse, my "before" query is as following (not working in all cases):

```
{ $sort: { type: -1, name: -1 } },
            {
               $match: {
                  name: { $lt: card.name },
                  type: { $lte: card.type }
               }
            },
{ $limit: 1 }
```

Comment: something like https://mongoplayground.net/p/AQUmjMcEaUy?

Comment: Thank you very much, this does seem to be what I need. I updated OP with before query if you could please help with that and post as answer. Thank you

Edit: or just answer with this, if i get before to work myself I'll accept

Comment: replace gt with lt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can write a match query which checks an `or` condition where check `type` is greater than the given type or if the type is equal to the given type then check if the `name` is greater than the given name. To get the before document replace `gt` with `lt`

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $sort: { type: 1, name: 1 } },
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        { type: { $gt: <type> } },
        { $and: [{ type: <type> }, { name: { $gt: <name> } }] }
      ]
    }
  },
  { $limit: 1 }
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AQUmjMcEaUy)